# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on History breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  9         18
Users destroyed                                 163          0
Users deleted                                     2          0
Users contacted                                  33          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           328        904
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              118        373
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         30        244
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               75        278
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               261      1,419
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              312      1,893
Tags merged                                       5          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             4          1
Tag synonyms created                              8          0
Revisions redacted                                2          0
Questions unprotected                             0          1
Questions reopened                               38          7
Questions protected                              44         40
Questions migrated                               32          0
Questions flagged⁴                                2        457
Questions closed                                351        341
Question flags handled⁴                         352        107
Posts unlocked                                    0          5
Posts undeleted                                  36         40
Posts locked                                      0         72
Posts deleted⁵                                  582        855
Posts bumped                                      0         92
Escalations to the CM team                        1          0
Comments undeleted                               85          0
Comments flagged                                416        802
Comments deleted⁶                             3,395      1,926
Comment flags handled                           974        244
Answers flagged                                  26        989
Answer flags handled                            860        155
All comments on a post moved to chat             88          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of History](https://history.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://history.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...